# Unable to create a document that has another embedded document inside it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After going through a node.js + mongodb tutorial, I'm trying to build a small project. But I'm stuck.
I'm trying to build a small ecommerce api. I have a seller collection, and an inventory collection. A seller can have many inventory items.
I have successfully created the seller collection, and I'm now trying to create the inventory collection. I have embedded the seller inside the inventory as such:

models/inventory.js

```
const { sellerSchema } = require("./seller");
.
.
.
const inventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  itemName: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 30 },
  itemDescription: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 10 },
  // look into how to upload and handle images on mongodb
  // image:,
  quantity: { type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 999 },
  category: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 20 },
  price: { type: Number, required: true, min: 0 },
  seller: { type: sellerSchema, required: true },
});

const Inventory = mongoose.model("Inventory", inventorySchema);

exports.Inventory = Inventory;
```

routes/inventories.js

```
const { Seller } = require("../models/seller");
const { Inventory } = require("../models/inventory");
.
.
.
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const seller = await Seller.findById(req.body.sellerId);
  if (!seller) return res.status(400).send("Seller not found");

  let inventory = new Inventory({
    itemName: req.body.itemName,
    itemDescription: req.body.itemDescription,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    category: req.body.category,
    price: req.body.price,
    seller: { _id: seller._id, name: seller.name },
  });

  inventory = await inventory.save();
  res.send(inventory);
});
```

When I try running this on postman
`http://localhost:3000/api/inventories/` in an attempt to create an item, this fails. The seller is not found. This is the object I'm sending on postman:

```
{"itemName": "itemName1",
"itemDescription": "itemDescription1",
"quantity": 1,
"category": "category1",
"price": 1,
"seller":"6531ea0358367cd5d863600d"
}
```

`6531ea0358367cd5d863600d` is id of an existing seller in the db. I extracted the seller id from sellers I successfully added to the sellers collection.
What am I missing?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the object you are sending via postman? Also, can you post the output from `console.log(req.body)` please? Also, what is `6531ea0358367cd5d863600d` referring to? In your route you are not collection it. All I can see is `router.post("/"`.

Comment: hi @jQueeny thanks for responding. 
From your comment I noticed I had incorrectly typed out the URL I was sending. I have since corrected that in the question. I have also added the object I'm sending.
`6531ea0358367cd5d863600d ` is the id of an existing seller in the database.

Comment: `id` in mongodb is an ObjectId. `"seller": ObjectId("<id>")`

Answer (score 0):

So the **quick fix answer** is to change `req.body.sellerId` to `req.body.seller` and add the `seller` document to the `new Inventory()` document like this:

```js
const seller = await Seller.findById(req.body.seller); //< req.body.seller
if (!seller) return res.status(400).send("Seller not found");

let inventory = new Inventory({
    itemName: req.body.itemName,
    itemDescription: req.body.itemDescription,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    category: req.body.category,
    price: req.body.price,
    seller: seller //< Add the seller object. That's what your inventorySchema expects
  });

//...
//...
```

That's because you don't have a `sellerId` in your postman data object, only `seller`.

The **long answer** is to improve your data modelling by using [referenced documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate). At the minute you are going to add the `Seller` document to every `Inventory` document. What happens if your `Seller` details change? Those changes won't cascade into each `Inventory` document.

Instead only add a reference to the `Seller` into each `Inventory` document. Make these schema changes:

```js
const inventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  itemName: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 30 },
  //...
  //...
  seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Seller', required: true },
});
```

Then when you create the `new Inventory({})` document:

```js
let inventory = new Inventory({
    itemName: req.body.itemName,
    //...
    //...
    seller: seller._id, //< Only add the seller ObjectId
  });
```

Now if your `Seller` details change they only change in the `Seller` document. Your new references will always point to the same document, no matter how many times you change it. This improves data consistency and reduces document size.

When you want to get the `Inventory` documents with the `Seller` documents included you can use `Model.populate` which will switch those new references with the corresponding `Seller` like so:

```
const inventory = Inventory.findById(id).populate('seller');
// or if the models havn't been registred
const inventory = Inventory.findById(id).populate({path: 'seller', model: Seller});
```